# Pika timeout issue with RabbitMQ

Tags: timeout, rabbitmq, pika

I am having issues with Pika giving a timeout error.  The same code (below) works fine in other environments, but fails in this one.

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=host))
```

rabbitmqctl status

```
    [{pid,30059},
 {running_applications,[{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","2.8.2"},
                        {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.4"},
                        {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.1.8"},
                        {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.4.12"},
                        {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.16.4"},
                        {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.13.4"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,"Erlang R13B03 (erts-5.7.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [rq:8] [async-threads:30] [hipe] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,[{total,76031440},
          {processes,57368952},
          {processes_used,57354128},
          {system,18662488},
          {atom,1119593},
          {atom_used,1112833},
          {binary,205008},
          {code,12015821},
          {ets,1407392}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.39999999993657753},
 {vm_memory_limit,5045529804},
 {disk_free_limit,12613824512},
 {disk_free,10839289856},
 {file_descriptors,[{total_limit,924},
                    {total_used,837},
                    {sockets_limit,829},
                    {sockets_used,829}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,6763}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,3298}]
...done.
```

Has anyone hit this before?  I'm assuming it is a rabbitmq configuration issue

Comment: Here is the solution for time out issue.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163308/pika-blocking-connection-py-random-timeout-connecting-to-rabbitmq/28103391#28103391


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163308/pika-blocking-connection-py-random-timeout-connecting-to-rabbitmq/28103391#28103391

Answer (score 0):

Check out the RabbitMQ log, you may need to supply login credentials:

```
pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host, port=port, virtual_host=vhost, credentials=pika.credentials.PlainCredentials(username, password)))
```